# error about django project path and module import rules

Tags: python, django

I generate a django project and its directory structure is like the following:

```
-myproject

    --__init__.py

    --settings.py

    --rooturls.py

    --dbUtils.py

    --app1

        ---__init__.py

        ---views.py

        ---urls.py

    --app2

        ---__init__.py

        ---views.py

        ---urls.py
```

I want to import dbUtils in my apps , so I configure in my settings.py:

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.insert(0, PROJECT_ROOT)
```

However, the program still can't find the module.

Comment: Just say import dbUtils in the place you are using it.

Comment: but I want to import it in other apps. If I place it in app1,I still cant't import it in app2....I want to set a global env to solve this problem,rather than place a copy of it in every app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying with wsgi setup, you need to update the path in your wsgi script most likely `wsgi.py`

Otherwise, update your `PYTHONPATH` for this path.

**UPDATE:** you can import as

```
from myproject import dbUtils
```

Updating `sys.path` in `settings.py` doesn't really a good place for that.

Comment: i ADD THE following codes in wsgi.py，it still doesn't work.PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.insert(0, PROJECT_ROOT)

Comment: @stackpop, check my update you can do `from myproject import dbUtils`